# if a value selected in combox1 then it should be disable in all other combo boxes

Tags: c#, combobox

if a value selected in combox1 then it should be disable in all other combo boxes. 
For Example I have 4 combo boxes. 
ComboBox1,ComboBox2,ComboBox3,ComboBox4.
All have same value e.g (1,2,3,4,5)
If value 1 is selected in ComboBox1 then it should be disable in all other and same for all Boxes???
Thanks I need Reply Quickl.
Waiting.
M USMAN

Comment: You can't deactivate in comboboxes. only remove

Comment: You need to listen to the SelectionChanged event.

Comment: refer http://www.chetanasforum.com/index.php?showtopic=2229

Answer (score 0):

You would have to remove the element from the other combo boxes, for example:

```
comboBox2.Items.Remove(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
```

You can handle the `ComboBox1 OnChange` event by doing:

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     // remove the item in the other lists based upon ComboBox1 selection
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On selection you would then need to remove it from the other combo boxes.
eg.

```
//On item selected in ComboBox1
private void showSelectedButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
{

    comboBox2.Items.Remove(comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString());
    comboBox3.Items.Remove(comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString());
    comboBox4.Items.Remove(comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: actually use the ComboBox1.SelectedItem method as proposed by @Darren Davies for robustness rather than the string "1" as I have suggested here

Comment: What if the user selects a different item than "1"?

Answer (score 0):

if you not only use 1stcomboBox to select item + remove from others and you use a generic list as combobox datasource; i guess you can use an extension method

```
    /// <summary>
    /// returns a new List<T> without the List<T> which won't have the given parameter 
    ///
    /// Example Usage of the extension method :
    ///
    /// List<int> nums = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    /// 
    /// List<int> i = nums.Without(3);
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TList"> Type of the Caller Generic List </typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T"> Type of the Parameter </typeparam>
    /// <param name="list"> Name of the caller list </param>
    /// <param name="item"> Generic item name which exclude from list </param>
    /// <returns>List<T> Returns a generic list </returns>

    public static TList Without<TList, T>(this TList list, T item) where TList : IList<T>, new()
        {
            TList l = new TList();

            foreach (T i in list.Where(n => !n.Equals(item)))
            {
                l.Add(i);
            }

            return l;
        }
```

Then You can set the datasource of which combobox as you want (List is very fast)

By the Way.. if you want to be sure that the item of combobox selected by mouse (user activity - not programatically) you need to use SelectionChangeCommitted event; not SelectedIndexChanged. With SelectedIndexChange event you will also catch when the combobox Loads the first time. But with SelectionChange Committed event waits enter keyboard or pressing Mouse to the arrow of combobox to fire itself